# Shading in bars in barchart in R

Tags: r, histogram

I'm using this code to make an overlapping histogram in R.

```
#Random numbers
h2<-rnorm(1000,4)
h1<-rnorm(1000,6)

# Histogram Colored (blue and red)
hist(h1, col=rgb(1,0,0,0.5),xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,200), main="Overlapping Histogram”, xlab="Variable”)
hist(h2, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5), add=T)
box()
```

This code produces this plot:

[overlapping histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hvzq.png)

What I've been trying to figure out is how I can make the darkness of the bars correspond to values in my data. In other words, for the variable "h1" how can I make larger values have darker colored bars?

Thanks!!

Comment: You may want to look at the recently released ggplot2 and its color scaling capablities [R blogger article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/overlapping-histogram-in-r/)

Answer (score 1):

It would much more easier to do using `ggplot2`. But you can also try to do it this way:

```
#Random numbers

set.seed(11235)

h1 <- rnorm(1000, 6)
h2 <- rnorm(1000, 4)

# Histogram Colored (blue and red), alpha value corresponds to freq.

hist(h1, 
     col=rgb(1, 0, 0, hist(h1, plot = F)$density),
     xlim = c(0, 10), 
     ylim = c(0, 200), 
     xlab='Variable',
     main='Overlapping Histogram'
     )
hist(h2, col = rgb(0, 0, 1, hist(h2, plot = F)$density), add = T)
box()
```

[image: alpha~frequency histogram]

```
# Histogram Colored (blue and red), alpha value corresponds 
# to variable value.

mynorm <- function(x){
  return((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
}
hist(h1, 
     col=rgb(1, 0, 0, mynorm(hist(h1, plot = F)$mids)),
     xlim = c(0, 10), 
     ylim = c(0, 200), 
     xlab='Variable',
     main='Overlapping Histogram'
)
hist(h2, col = rgb(0, 0, 1, mynorm(hist(h2, plot = F)$mids)), add = T)
box()
```

[image: alpha~variable value]

So you simply use frequencies|variable-values as a alpha-values in your rgb-color specification.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This worked beautifully! One follow up question: How can I make it so that shading gets darker higher values for one variable (the blue one on the left) and lighter for higher values on the other (the one on the right)?

Comment: You just have to reverse the vector of alpha values in h1:

`rev(mynorm(hist(h1, plot = F)$mids))`

You will get something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l1jyrow9q1b5gur/baseHist.jpeg?dl=0)  

But it's kinda sport to do such things this way. I haven't tried it yet, but I think that with `ggplot2` it would be much easier.